# Common logic between various Laravel controllers method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Let's say I have an URL like this:

```
/city/nyc   (display info about new york city)
```

and another like this:

```
/city/nyc/streets   (display a list of Street of nyc)
```

I can bind them to a method like this:

```
Route::get('city/{city}', 'CityController@showCity');
Route::get('city/{city}/streets', 'CityController@showCityStreet');
```

The problem is that I need to execute some checks on the city (for example if {city} is present in the database) on both methods. 
I could create a method and call them in both like this:

```
class CityController {

    private function cityCommonCheck($city) {
       // check
    }

    public function showCity($city) {
      $this->cityCommonCheck($city);

      // other logic
    }

    public function showCityStreet($city) {
      $this->cityCommonCheck($city);

      // other logic
    }
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: You could write a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) for it

Comment: I don't think a middleware is the best option for this, I was thinking to put the check inside the constructor of the controller, but how can I access {city} from constructor?

Comment: Why do you think that? You can access `{city}` using the route facade `Route::input('city')` or by injecting the `Router` class `$router->input('city')`

Comment: Yes, in the __constructor i could use Route::input('city'); but maybe it'is better if we leave it off in a separate method (cityCommonCheck) so we can call it only on the route that we need

Comment: I don't get why you think this is not an appropriate use for middleware. It is *exactly* what middleware should be used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best way to do this, you can move common logic into a Model.So your code would like below.

```
class CityController {

  public function showCity($city) {
      City::cityCommonCheck($city);  
  }

  public function showCityStreet($city) {
    City::cityCommonCheck($city);
  }
}
```

## model class

```
class City{
    public static function cityCommonCheck($city) {
      //put here your logic
    }
}
```

In this way you could invoke cityCommonCheck function from any controller.

Comment: Interesting, altho that's not much different from my solution, I can declare my method static too and call from anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Even though you think differently, I believe a middleware is the best solution for this.

First, use `php artisan make:middleware CityCheckMiddleware` to create a class in `App/Http/Middleware`. Then edit the method to do what your check is supposed to do and add a constructor to inject the `Router`

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Routing\Router $router){
    $this->route = $router;
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $city = $this->route->input('city');

    // do checking

    return $next($request);
}
```

Define a shorthand key in `App/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    // ...
    'city_checker' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CityCheckerMiddleware',
];
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('city_checker', ['only' => ['showCity', 'showCityStreet']]);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, but other than checks, my method return some data (the row of the city). I don't think I can tell to a middleware to pass that data to a controller, or can I?

Comment: Well you could work around this and pass it using the session or some kind of other global storage but that's not really the purpose of middleware. If you call your function to get some data then you should leave it in the controller or better move it to the model or a repository/helper class.